# Are there any "Hollywood-style" movies made in Iran?

Tags: iranian-cinema

I have watched a lot of Iranian movies and I love them but they are similar in style (realistic long shots and slow cuts) and content (e.g. struggle of the society reflecting in children or seemingly mundane events). I doubt if all Iranians solely love this kind of movies. Japan, Korea, China, India, and Thailand have their commercial films besides independent art films going around in film festival circuit.

Is there a commercial movie industry in Iran making action or comedy films?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are in doubt if all Iranians solely love this kind of movies - you are right. From talks with Iranians some years ago, I know they like Hollywood films and the films were available via DVD.

Wikipedia offers more information about [Commercial cinema in Iran](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cinema_of_Iran#Commercial_cinema_in_Iran)

Answer (score 1):

There are no such movies in Iran because of:

1. The Iranian cinema is a very poor industry.
2. Modern devices are very expensive and you cannot them find in Iran.
3. Government has lots of attention and is sensitive about what would be made. So they make lots of sponsorship before a movie goes to start.
4. The is no connection between Iranian movie companies and the other companies outside Iran.

Comment: Not agree! What does “Hollywood-style” mean?